# WCS download and export to GeoTIFF problem

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, wcs

I want to download a Digital Elevation Model (DEM), more precise a Digital Terrain Model (DTM) from a WCS-Server using QGIS 3.28.3 and export it as a GeoTIFF file.

WCS-Server: https://gis.stmk.gv.at/arcgis/services/OGD/ALSGelaendeinformation_1m_UTM33N/MapServer/WCSServer

Download-Request of a 1x1 km area with 1 m resolution: https://gis.stmk.gv.at/arcgis/services/OGD/ALSGelaendeinformation_1m_UTM33N/MapServer/WCSServer?request=GetCoverage&version=1.0.0&service=WCS&coverage=4&CRS=EPSG:32633&bbox=500000,5200000,501000,5201000&format=GeoTIFF&RESX=1&RESY=1&interpolation=bilinear

So within QGIS I defined a new WCS-Layer with the above WCS-Server URL, connected to Layer-ID "3" (="Gelaendehoehe_Gesamtmodell"). Coordinate-Reference-System="EPSG:32633", Format = "GeoTIFF / GTiff". I also switched the QGIS-Project-CRS to "EPSG:32633"

After some seconds the WCS-layer is displayed in QGIS and look OK:

[image]

Now I right-click onto "4" in the layer list, *"Export > Save as > GeoTIFF"*. Enter a filename, "CRS" and "Extend" is already filled with the correct values. I changed the Resolution to Horizontal and Vertical: 1.0 (= 1m)

But now the export creates a faulty GeoTIFF, a 2x2 tiled file of the original image. Of course its georeferencing is also completely wrong:

[image]

I noticed if downloading the DTM with rougher resolutions e.g. 2 m or 10 m this is done correct, but how to download and export the DTM with 1 m resolution in a correct way? Or is this a recent bug of QGIS?

Comment: Why not save directly from the wcs?

Comment: I already did via the download-link I posted above. But I also want QGIS to do this task correct and am wondering why it does not.

Comment: Check was GetCoverage request QGIS really makes. Hopefully the debugging/developer tools show them. QGIS at least used to use WCS like it was a substitute for WMS. By that I mean that QGIS is using the extent of the map view and count of pixels on the screen and asks WCS server to send a resampled output instead of doing simple GetCoverage with the default resolution.

Comment: The situation seems to be just like I thought and QGIS is using WCS for showing the data, not for downloading the data in original resolution. Here is one query that is created by QGIS: https://gis.stmk.gv.at/arcgis/services/OGD/ALSGelaendeinformation_1m_UTM33N/MapServer/WCSServer?SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&FORMAT=GeoTIFF&COVERAGE=3&BBOX=526676.91376547119580209,5207670.2033759132027626,541530.68550460156984627,5217021.57427007332444191&CRS=EPSG:32633&RESPONSE_CRS=EPSG:32633&WIDTH=1096&HEIGHT=690

Comment: Export to file does work for me and imagery is captured at desired resolution. Could you clarify what URL did you use as a connection? Just the service address https://gis.stmk.gv.at/arcgis/services/OGD/ALSGelaendeinformation_1m_UTM33N/MapServer/WCSServer or the one with BBOX etc?

Comment: I used the short on without BBOX: "https://gis.stmk.gv.at/arcgis/services/OGD/ALSGelaendeinformation_1m_UTM33N/MapServer/WCSServer"